# WebGL: missing triangles when moving camera

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, webgl

I am rendering a complex scene in WebGL (180 meshes) corresponding to a car model (Nissan GTX) [image: car]. However when I move the camera around , it seems as if triangles were missing [image: far],

These 'missing triangles' seem to jump randomly over the surface. Can this be a depth buffer problem or a normal calculation problem? I have no idea.

Nevertheless, if I zoom-in near the surface of the model, all triangles are there  [image: zoom].

Does anyone have had this problem? any tips?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you have a wireframe mesh directly on top of (or very near) a solid mesh and this is just a depth buffer problem. It works when zooming in, because the depth buffer precision is higher in the near area of the viewing frustum.

Try adjusting the screen space depth by working with the polygon offset (or a similar fragment shader modifying `gl_FragDepth`) when rendering a wireframe overlay directly on top of the solid mesh. Or just move them farther away in object space.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the zNear parameter in the perspective matrix from 0.1 to 10 and the problem was gone!

Answer (score 1):

You might be right when you suspect a depth-buffer problem - the fact that the distance to the camera affects things suggests it could be a buffer precision problem. Check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449943/surfaces-got-broken-when-object-is-far-away-in-iphone/5456188) for a possible solution.